# Notify the change in directory in a website asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I want to implement OBSERVER pattern for a website to raise a event if the content of a particular server directory (including sub directory) is changed (files added or deleted or modified). Moreover the directory can't be accessed via mapping in the website url.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you want to check if inside a folder has been **added** or **deleted** an item you might use:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> allSubDirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>();

DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo("/Path/To/Base/Directory/Here");

foreach(DirectoryInfo di in myDir.GetDirectories())
{
    allSubDirectories.Add(di);
}
```

Now allSubDirectories holds info of all directories inside the base directory, and in the same manner you can retrieve the inner directories.

So now we should check if something is added or removed like so:

```
int numberOfFiles = someDir.GetFiles().Length; // This will retrieve how much files are there at the start
```

Then you can easly check if the length is different from some DateTime or depending on your needs

Now to check if a file has been modified, check the examples here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

The class FileSystemWatcher has event Changed wich will give information if the file was opened, changed, modified size, modified file name and other info.